# Is there a way to check if an integer's string representation contains a zero by using bitwise operations?

Tags: language-agnostic, bit-manipulation, data-processing

In C# I've been trying to come up with an interesting way to basically accomplish the following, but without using the string representation.

```
private static bool HasZeroDigit(int value)
{
    string text = value.ToString();
    if (text.Contains("0"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My first attempt was some trickery along the lines of checking if a byte in the binary representation of the absolute value contains a zero byte, but obviously that doesn't map correctly. Though it got me thinking if this would be on the right track with some adjustment for how integers map to individual characters.

My incorrect first attempt:

```
private static bool HasZeroDigit(int value)
{
    uint temp = value >= 0 ? (uint)value : (uint)-value;
    if (temp <= UInt16.MaxValue)
    {
        ushort temp16 = (ushort)temp;
        return ~((((temp16 & 0x7F7F) + 0x7F7F) | temp16) | 0x7F7F) != 0;
    }

    bool hasZero = ~((((temp & 0x7F7F7F7F) + 0x7F7F7F7F) | temp) | 0x7F7F7F7F) != 0;
    return hasZero;
}
```

So, is there a way to check if an integer contains a zero digit without actually turning it into a string? The goal here is computational efficiency.

Suggestions and solutions in any language are welcome.

Comment: Bitwise, I don't know. You're not entirely clear on which base you want to use. If you want to check for zeroes in decimal numbers, `bool HasZeroDigit(int value) { if (value == 0) return true; while(value != 0) { if (value % 10 == 0) return true; else value /= 10; } return false; }` should work, but that doesn't use 'only bitwise operations' ;)